# Conditional redirect with React Router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my React app, I sometimes need to do a conditional redirect.

For example, I send users to a landing page and depending on a button user clicks, I store a value in `sessionStorage` and log in the user which automatically takes the user to home screen.

That’s where I want to do a conditional redirect. For example, if the value I stored in `sessionStorage` is “basketball“, I want to redirect user to basketball news page. If no value was stored, I’ll leave user on home screen.

I can handle this with `window.location.replace` but that’s causing a page postback. I’d rather handle this redirect the React way by loading the appropriate component, rather than doing a page postback.

Can I do this with React Router 4?

Comment: Yes... Here is the link to the docs... https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Comment: Then it's just a matter of a conditional render if (condition) { <Redirect to="/basketball" /> } else { etc etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `<Redirect>` component and wrap it in conditionals :

```
//...
render() {
    const isBasketBall = sessionStorage.get('something') === 'basketball';
    return (
        {isBasketBall && <Redirect to="/basketball-news" />}
        {!isBasketBall && <Redirect to="/home" />}
    );
}
//...
```

Official docs has a [nice example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) with authentication workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this instead of Redirect:

```
{ isBasketBall && this.props.history.push("/basketball-news") }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    return (
        sessionStorage.get('redirectpath') ? this.props.history.push("/" + sessionStorage.get('redirectpath')) : this.props.history.push("/")
    );
}
```

Comment: Please add some comments.